# Redundant 'let' call removal alters the semantic

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I wrote a code that checks if a number is within a range, the code reads first the number to check then the endpoints values of the range.

The code seems to be fine

```
fun main() = read().let { print(it  in read()..read()) }
fun read() = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

If I enter the sequence: 20, 10, 30 I get the expected result (true)

But then the IDE gives me a warning, saying that redundant 'let' call could be removed

[image]

And when I click on Remove `let` call I get the following code:

```
fun main() = print(read() in read()..read())
fun read() = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

Which gives me an opposite result (false) using the same sequence 20, 10, 30

I'm quite new in Kotlin, but I'm puzzled because my very first code was the version without the `let` call, and I've used the scope function to verify it after getting the strange output, I hope someone could explain this.

The IDE details:
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.5080.55, built on August 24, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.16 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7

Comment: The warning that you show from the IDE doesn't seem to be for the same code as above. You don't use the `it` parameter in `let`'s lambda there

Comment: Sorry got the wrong screenshot, I'll rectify it

Comment: For the record, I tried when using the `it` inside, and I got the same warning too. I believe this is a bug of the inspection because it's not equivalent. That being said, I believe you should avoid relying on the evaluation order of these `read()` calls. It would be more appropriate to define variables as suggested in @Merig's answer to make it clear what order you expect (it's also clearer to the reader IMO)

Comment: I can understand that my code is not readable, maybe not conventional, but I wanted to verify if the auto code refactoring of the IDE is not working properly, if it's the case, then probably it's a bug.

Comment: There are already a bunch of open bug tickets for all essentially the same issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12808 (see the linked tickets, etc). Not much to do except to suppress this warning.

Comment: @somethingsomething Thank you for the link, I've posted the issue there too, basically a copie of this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The scope block ensures that your first `read()` runs before the 2 range ones. When you remove it my guess is that the order of operation changes and the values don't go where you expect them.

Try something like

```
val numberToCheck = read()
val range = read()..read()
print(numberToCheck in range)
```

Comment: So you mean that the complier execute the read()..read() and then do the check read() in read()..read()? and if it's the case why the IDE refactor the code to a wrong version?

Comment: What the IDE is telling you is that the `let` is unnecessary, because you called it on a non-nullable value. It doesn't know what your intent is, so it's not giving you a "wrong" version but one syntactically correct that gives you something different that what you wanted.

Comment: the IDE is just saying that `let' is redundant, as In the picture

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler builds the `IntRange` first (which requires the 2nd and 3rd `read` calls), then performs the 1st `read` and checks if that value is `in` the range. In this case the call order matters (like needing to be careful about things like `i++` and `++i`) so the ``let`` version isn't equivalent in this case (the linter doesn't always get it right!)

Comment: On the other hand, the only reason to use the `let` version is if you *know* the execution order in the plain statement, and you want to wrangle it, so you know to ignore/suppress that warning. Or better - rewrite it more explicitly, reading your variables in order and assigning them to clearly named `val`s (or the first `read` at the very least). The fact you already got tripped up by this, and then the compiler did, is a good sign this is extremely brittle and bug-prone code, and you're not really gaining anything by making it terse. (Plus you can really overdo the `let`s, I've been there!)

Comment: @cactustictacs How do you suppress this warning?

Comment: @Agent_L if you follow the *More Options* link in the warning popup in the OP, you'll get a *Remove 'let' call* option. If you hit the right arrow on that, you'll get some options about the issue, including adding a `Suppress` annotation for that warning. So in this case it's `@Suppress("ComplexRedundantLet")`, but it's the same for any warning. Also I wouldn't suppress it, like the discussion gets into it's a source of potential bugs - probably better to rewrite it explicitly